# Cocoa pods install inside user directory(without sudo)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoapods

I can only access my directory, so I want to install the cocoa pods to the users directory. How can I achieve this?
I follow the below link but is not working.
[Sudo-less installation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#sudo-less-installation) 
Please assist me how to achieve this.
I'll be very thankful if any one provide me step by step procedure to achieve this.

What I tried

```
gem install cocoapods --user-install
```

Error I'm getting

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:959:in `read': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/specifications/terminal-notifier-1.6.0.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:959:in `load'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:644:in `block (2 levels) in each_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:643:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:643:in `block in each_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:642:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:642:in `each_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:658:in `each_normal'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:669:in `_all'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:431:in `map'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:431:in `find_files'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:942:in `load_plugins'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/bin/gem:9:in `<main>'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using ruby shipped with OS X?

Comment: What didn't work in the link you tried?

Comment: @Cheng-Yu Hsu Ya I'm using the same which shipped with OS X

Comment: @NobodyNada I updated the question, please refer it

Comment: @SandeepKumar got any answer?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Ya, I fixed the issue with Homebrew and bundler

Comment: @SandeepKumar I did try but nothing happens. Can u share the steps as an answer?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Sure, can you please share the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the steps which worked form me (In case any one need this).

I used `Homebrew` and `bundler`

Install homebrew: 
`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Install brew-gem:
`brew install brew-gem`

Install bundler: 
`brew gem install bundler`
`bundler` is a package management tool which provides a consistent environment for Ruby projects by tracking and installing the exact gems and versions that are needed.

Then add `cocoapod` in `gemfile` (if `gemfile` is missing then, use `bundle init` to create `gemfile`).

Then naviaged to your project directory and execute following command

`bundle install --path vendor`

The above command will look the `gemfile` and install the all the gems in the `vendor` directory.

Now onward prefix the `bundle exe` to add the cocoapod commands. 
i.e

`bundle exec pod install`

`bundle exec pod update`